# Tiny Core Linux: wget: can't execute 'openssl': No such file or directory

Tags: openssl, wget, tiny-core-linux

In Tiny Core Linux I get this error if I try to download from a https URL:

```
wget -O foo https://example.com/foo

wget: can't execute 'openssl': No such file or directory
```

I tried to install `openssl` but this failed:

```
sudo -u tc tce-load -wi openssl

Downloading: openssl.tcz
Connecting to repo.tinycorelinux.net (128.127.66.77:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
md5sum: openssl.tcz.md5.txt: No such file or directory
Error on openssl.tcz
```

How can I make `wget` work in tcl?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `TinyCore-14.0.iso` image, which seems to run a reduced `wget`.

After installing `wget`, it worked:

```
sudo -u tc tce-load -wi wget
```

Background: I use `sudo` here because this code runs in a bootlocal.sh script.